# Closure Conditional - How does this returning function get the value set as a parameter when its not passed as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, closures

So, `return function (n)` still returns the value that was initially given to its parent function as an augment. But i don't get why, when i haven't passed n's value from `var digit_name = (function(){` does `return function(n){` get its value from the original argument.

Especially as I have overwritten it with `var n = 4;`

**JS**

```
   var digit_name = (function(){
       var names;
       var n = 4;
       return function(n){
           if(!names){
               names = ['zero','one','two','three'];
           }
       return names[n];
       }
   }());
   console.info(digit_name(3)); //Three
```

Also if I overwrite `return function(n)` with a number `return function(1)` I will `SyntaxError: missing formal parameter`. I understand that return names[n] wouldn't then know what `n`, so why not give a `n is undefined` error?

Comment: you can't call digit_name(3) because digital_name does not receive a parameter, also notice that you're using self-invoked function(don't know why)

Comment: no, it's okay to call it. it is obvious it returns "three", doesn't it?

Comment: @RodrigoDias just paste this code into your console, you will see that it does receive a parameter as it is the inner function

Comment: certainly does @varnie. @Rodrigo The magic of why this works right? this was the whole basis of the question, how does returning function get the value set on `digit_name(3)`? the reason for self-invoking is so that it runs on page load :)

Comment: after some testing indeed works, but is really overcomplicated

Comment: depends what you need it to work for :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, so I'm just going to explain why you get the output you do...

When the code runs, the IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) is executed and `digit_name` refers to the function returned from it. That function still has access to the outer `n` and `names` variables via a closure.

You then invoke `digit_name` and pass it an argument. The formal parameter of `digit_name` is `n`, which shadows the `n` declared in the outer scope. There is no longer any way you can refer to that outer `n`. So whatever value you pass into `digit_name` will be used.

Effectively, the IIFE in this case is pointless (apart from the fact that it prevents you from having to create the array every time the function is invoked) and your code is equivalent to this except for that array difference:

```
var digit_name = function (n) {
    return ['zero','one','two','three'][n];
};
console.info(digit_name(3)); // "three"
```

Comment: genius. Indeed, this example was showing how to stop yourself, when needing a set of data, of redeclaring it over and over. I had never thought to us IIFE as a closure. What i did not know about, wanted to know about, was how the argument got from the original function to the returning function.

Comment: @JamieHutber - I'm still not really sure what you mean... by "original function" do you mean the IIFE? If so, it doesn't have any arguments. It just returns a function. You can pretty much ignore the `n` and `names` declarations inside the IIFE since you can't access `n` after it returns - you've shadowed it by naming an argument of the child function `n`.

Comment: yep, thanks for reading between my screen of mass confusion. Indeed, i was wondering why we didn't pass the IIFE a parameter. I my example `n`.

Comment: @JamieHutber - Oh I see. To put it simply, you don't pass the IIFE a parameter because it executes immediately. When the code following it executes, it's as if the IIFE isn't even there, just the return value of it. Since the return value of it is a function, you can just call it like any other function. You can imagine this effect as the code in my answer.

Comment: indeed. Exactly what I was wondering about. The fact that is executes straight away I didn't realise would have an impact. But of course it returns the value, which in this case (and most) is a function which is where we're using the parameter. Also the `formal parameter` this can be given any name. Just happens that I called it `n`. I have tried to write down my understand. But as you can tell writing clearly is not my forte. I understand, in one word closures is why `var n = 1` won't equal one within the returning function.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the definition of digit_name in the console you will see it is this function:

```
   function (n){
       if(!names){
           names = ['zero','one','two','three'];
       }
       return names[n];
   }
```

So you haven't overwritten n, since the scope of n within this function is now the parameter n, not the variable declared above.

Comment: yep got it, thats the closure working right there. So how does it get the value of n?

Comment: you are passing it in as a parameter when you call digit_name(3)

Comment: so the anonymous function isn't where you would set the parameter, for example this isn't how you would do it: `var digit_name = (function(n){`

Comment: @JamieHutber sorry, not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have a naming and scope collision with the variable `n`. The defined `var n` in the outer function is assigned a value of 4. Your inner function accepts a single parameter declared as `n`. So, the `n` variable in your inner function is referring to its' internal scope and no longer refers to `var n` in the outer function. If you want a default value, you can name the outer variable something different and check for an existence of the value `n` in your inner function:

```
var digit_name = (function () {
    var names;
    var defaultn = 0;
    return function (n) {
        if (!n) n = defaultn;
        if (!names) {
            names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
        }
        return names[n];
    }
}());
console.info(digit_name(3)); //Three
console.info(digit_name()); //zero
```